# Streaming FLV files directly from the database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem with a homework. We are supposed to program a website that makes it possible to upload video files directly into a longblob field of a database and then watch the videos directly from there. We have to support MP4, FLV and AVI files.
MP4 video playing works already, but something is not worling for me when I want to play FLV files.

I'm using XAMPP to develop and the following code bellow is what I tried so far:

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Videos", $user, $pass);
$type = $db->query('SELECT format FROM videos WHERE `videoid` = "'.$_GET["videoid"].'"');
$video = $db->query('SELECT inhalt FROM videos WHERE `videoid` = "'.$_GET["videoid"].'"');

if($type->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) == 'MP4')
{
    echo '<div content="Content-Type: video/mp4">
                      <video width="700" height="450" controls="controls" poster="image" preload="metadata">
                      <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,'.base64_encode($video->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)).'"/>;
                  </video>
              </div>';
}
if($type->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) == 'FLV')
{
    echo'
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480"
        data-setup=\'{"controls" : true, "autoplay" : true, "preload" : "auto"}\'>
        <source src="data:video/x-flv;base64,'.base64_encode($video->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)).'" type="video/x-flv"/>
    </video>
    </body>
    </html>';
}
?>
```

As I have said, MP4 files work fine but the FLV doesn't. I just get a black video window. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong when I want to play that file?

Comment: What does the client-side code do with the content? Looks like your FLV version returns an entire `<html>` document, while the MP4 version just returns a fragment.

Comment: Also for what it's worth your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: It's not all completely finished yet, I'm still working on the video functionality before I complete the website. You are right about the SQL injection. I will include a check, to check if the videoid is a number